# How to make angle pop out more with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

I have just started with tikz and I am trying to create a right triangle. However, when I try to draw an angle it keeps becoming squished. Is there some way to move it forward to become less squished (like with `angle eccentricity`)?

My code:

```latex
% tikz packages used:
% \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes, angles}
\begin{diagram}[scale=0.4]
    % coordinates
    \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (B) at (19, 0);
    \coordinate (C) at (19, 5);

    % draw sides of vector triangle
    \draw[-{Triangle[open]}, darkred, ultra thick]
        (A) -- (B)
        node[midway, below, black]{$\vect r_x$};
    \draw[-{Triangle[open]}, darkred, ultra thick]
        (B) -- (C)
        node[midway, right, black]{$\vect r_y$};
    \draw[-{Triangle[open]}, darkred, ultra thick]
        (A) -- (C)
        node[midway, above left, black]{$\vect r$};

    % label stuff
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=5]{angle=B--A--C};
    \pic [draw, angle eccentricity=.5]{right angle=A--B--C};
\end{diagram}
```

Result:

[image: Rendering result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{6*sqrt(3)}
        \draw (0,0)--(6,0);
        \draw (0,0)--(6,\a);
        \foreach \i in {.5,.75,...,5.5}
            \draw[->] (\i,0) arc (0:60:\i);
        \draw[->,red] (5.5,0) arc (0:60:5.5) node[midway,fill=white] () {$60^\circ$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it [here](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.22)!

Just have to change the line

```latex
\pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=5]{angle=B--A--C};
```

to

```latex
\pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.25, angle radius=2cm]{angle=B--A--C};
```